# ViewController shows objects not from origin 0

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I am having an issue when going to a new `ViewController`:
The new `ViewController` has `scrollView` in it which starts at `origin y: 0`.
The `scrollView` has a `textView` that starts at `origin y: 0`.

BUT when I run the app on the **simulator**, it shows me the `textView` somewhere around the middle of the screen, for some reason.

**I added the scrollView and the textView programmatically.**

Here is my code:

```
class addViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

     var textView = UITextView()
     var scrollView = UIScrollView()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        textView.frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 0, width: 250.0, height: 100.0)
        textView.center = self.view.center
        textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
        textView.textColor = UIColor.blue
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        textView.text = "texttttt"

        scrollView.addSubview(textView)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

To get to this `ViewController` - You click on a cell in the previous `ViewController`, this is code inside the `didSelectCellAt`:

```
let addNoteVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addViewController") as! addViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addNoteVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reconsider your line `textView.center = self.view.center`. This will override the frame you set before. And since you seem to know where to put it with your frame just delete it

Comment: Happens to the best of us :D